# Insert data into the database with FullCalendar and Python/Django

Tags: python-3.x, fullcalendar, django-2.0

I'm having trouble inserting, editing, and deleting event data with FullCalendar in a web app I'm developing

I would like everything to work on the same screen, that is, when the user selects dates in the calendar, the modal appears to insert the values (title and dates), when you click on an event, the modal to edit the event appears and a button to remove it.

So far what I could do was the following:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        navLinks: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function (start, end) {
            $('#cadastrar #start').val(moment(start).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#cadastrar #end').val(moment(end).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#cadastrar').modal('show');
        },
    });

});

<script>
```

In **template** (agenda/agenda.html) I did it, which corresponds to the schedule and the modal that is opened when any date in the calendar is selected.

```html
<section class="content">
     <div id='calendar'></div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="cadastrar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
         data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Cadastrar Evento</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{form.event_name}}
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{form.start_date}}
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{form.end_date}}
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              {{form.event_type}}
                          </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In **models.py** created the following

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_name
```

**views**

```py
class AddEventView(CustomCreateView):
    form_class = EventForm
    template_name = "agenda/agenda.html"
    permission_codename = 'add_event'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AddEventView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AddEventView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)

        return self.form_invalid(form)

class EventsListView(CustomListView):
    template_name = 'agenda/agenda.html'
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'all_eventos'
    permission_codename = 'view_eventos'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventosListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


class EditEventView(CustomUpdateView):
    form_class = EventForm
    model = Event
    template_name = "agenda/agenda.html"
    permission_codename = 'change_event'

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditEventView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = form_class(request.POST, instance=self.object)

        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)

        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**urls**

```py
   url(r'agenda/add/$',
        views.AddEventView.as_view(), name='addeventview'),

    url(r'agenda/$',
        views.EventsListView.as_view(), name='listeventsview'),

    url(r'agenda/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
        views.EditEventView.as_view(), name='editeventview'),
```

How do I call modal so that I can register, edit, and delete events? So far the modal opens, but no information appears. The problem certainly is in the **view**, but how do I make it Create, Edit and Delete on the same page and in the same modal?

Comment: Just a note: `moment(start).format` is unnecessary because `start` is already a moment. `start.format` will work fine. Same for `end`.

Comment: Regarding "no information appears" ...what HTML is produced by `{{form.start_date}}`? (I'm not familiar with python/Django, only fullCalendar). I'm thinking maybe `$('#cadastrar #start')` doesn't actually match any elements and therefore does not write the value into the field. But I don't know what ID is assigned to the HTML element which the python code produces.

Comment: Another note: `$('#cadastrar #start')` is also unnecessary. Since IDs must be unique in a HTML document, then you should be able to just write `$('#start')` and it will find the element with `id="start"` without needing to filter down to "cadastrar" first